# Reusing C# class in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that can contain a minimum of one "person" up to a maximum of fours "persons".  I am using view models and manually mapping in the controller to the domain model.

I am completely lost as to how to include more than one "person" in the app.  I've read up on using for but can't wrap my head around it.

Right now, I am just adding the data from the "person" class manually such that

Code:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public Guid SomeClassId {get; set;}
    public string BorrowerFirst { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerMI { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerLast { get; set; }
    public Suffix? BorrowerSuffix { get; set; }
    ...  some more fields ...
}
```

and so on in the master class.

What I'd like to do is use a class such as:

Code:

```
public class Applicant
{
    public string BorrowerFirst { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerMI { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerLast { get; set; }
    public Suffix? BorrowerSuffix { get; set; }
}
```

can be reused in another class multiple times.

How can I separate that to strip that and instead use a named class consisting of first, middle and last names and allowing up to four "person" instances in my master class?

Comment: show us some code, only description is not enough

Comment: So, you want  an "application" that can contain up to four "borrowers"?

Comment: Use Arry or List of "Person" in your view model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried inheritance?

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid SomeClassId {get; set;}
    public string BorrowerFirst { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerMI { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerLast { get; set; }
    public Suffix? BorrowerSuffix { get; set; }
}
```

and the Applicant class:

```
public class Applicant : Person
{
    //Only extra properties and methods here.

    public string FullName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.BorrowerFirst + " " + this.BorrowerMI + " " + this.BorrowerLast;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then have a vendor as well:

```
public class Vendor: Person
{
    //Only extra properties and methods here.
}
```